# How to plot RL Agent training returns without it looking like a mess

Tags: matplotlib, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am exercising on reinforcement learning basics on the frozen lake openai gym environment. My Q-learning agent trains for several tens of thousands of episodes and gets evaluated at regular intervals during training. Everything seems to be working because the q-table at the end of a training run looks good.

My question is : is there a better way to plot my data ? To make it clearer and cleaner. For training as well as evaluation.

When I plot my results (episodes on the X axis and score on the Y axis), I feel like the trend for the evaluations plot looks good because it quickly increases at the start and then stays around the same level.
But I also want to plot the returns that I get during training. The thing is, if my agent gets a run with score .5 and a run with score 0, and does that the whole way through, the curve is really ugly.
So I decided to plot the score at each episode averaged over 20 runs with some error bars for standard deviation. But doing that, I still get something really messy.

Here is an example of the kinds of graphs I get : [current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1v7A.png)
I plot the training returns as just a normal plot with errorbars (I think?) with matplotlib, and the evaluation returns as red circles.